# Rails 4 model: How to create record using json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My nested model looks like following

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks
end

class Project::Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :task_id, :name
  belongs_to :Project
end
```

My json data which I'm building by reading csv files:

```
"project": {
      "name": "My Project Name",
      "tasks_attributes": [
        {"name": "Design prototype"},
        {"name": "Home page UI  prototype"},
        {"name": "Other Miscellaneous task"}
     ]
}
```

I know I can let rails model create the record by posting above json to create method of following controller.

```
project_params = params.require(:project).permit(:name, tasks_attributes: [:name])
Project.new(project_params)
```

Since I have csv file uploaded on server which is further transformed in to json, I want to pass the json data directly to model to create records (nested) inside db. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're allowing users to upload CSV files, or whether you're doing it manually on the server.

--

If you're doing it on the server, I would use a [`Rake` task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake); if you're allowing the upload, you could use a controller action. The code would remain similar in both circumstances:

```
#CSV on Server
#lib/tasks/csv_process.rake
namespace :csv do
  desc "Process the CSV"
  task :process => :environment do
    file_name = File["path/to/file"]
    CSV.foreach(file_name, :headers => true) do |row|
        Project.create row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

This rake task can then be run by using `rake csv:process`, which can either be run manually from the server bash shell, or by tying it to a [`cron job`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

--

If you wanted to pass the CSV's to your app directly (although I've not done this before), you'd use a controller action such as the following:

```
#app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
   def create
        file = project_params[:file]
        CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
            Project.new row.to_hash
        end
   end

   private

   def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:file)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer how to be able to save json data, here's what you could do:

1. Parse your csv and build your json => `data = your_json_here`
2. `instance = YourModel.new(JSON.parse(data))` # this converts your json data into hash
3. `instance.save`

Not tested but this is the quickest things that comes to my mind. 
Ensure to check the params before you save the data (Again thats a check you need to do)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can anyone tell me why the answer is down voted ? Does it not answer you question or is the answer wrong ? Or is it out of context ? In every sense, this answer does answer the question and I see no reason for it to be down voted. Would love to have some explanation from the down voter, may be I'm missing something.

Comment: `save` is not a method on model class. Perhaps, that was a reason for downvote.

Comment: Fixed that :) It was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the CSV by using the [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

It will create a `Hash` and you will be able to pass it to you model.

But take care which parameters are passed. Check them before sending them to your database. Otherwise you will risk unallowed access to protected attributes. For example the user could modify a `role` attribute if present in your database.

You can read more about this vulnerability in the docs of [Strong Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Happy coding :).